# Has anyone ported the Bitcoin software to plain C or Objective C?

Tags: client, port

I'm not a big proponent of either C++ or Boost. Has there been any attempt to rewrite Bitcoin in plain ANSI C, or maybe Objective C? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

There is a pure C99 bitcoin implementation called [cbitcoin](https://github.com/MatthewLM/cbitcoin) by MatthewLM, forum threads:

- [cbitcoin - Bitcoin implementation in C. Currently in development.](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=80521.0)
- [[ANN] cbitcoin 1.0 Alpha 3 Released.](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=109312.0)

but it is currently in alpha stage. One of its features is weak library dependency, e.g. it possible to implement cryptography using something other than OpenSSL. As far as I know there is no Objective C Bitcoin implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C library is CoreBitcoin: http://github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin

Comment: Please give additional information about the stage the library is in.

Answer (score 0):

**picocoin** / **libccoin** available at https://github.com/jgarzik/picocoin